# Regarding Initial Data load for Migration

Tags: workbench

We are planning to do a migration fro seibral to saleforce. Initially we thought of using Jitterbit for the initial data load. but we have thoughts on using the Workbench tool in salesorce for the Initial data load. Can you please lt me know the pros and cons of bth of them and let us know the best tool for the intial data load activty? Intially we have plans to roll out some around for 500 users.

Answer (score 1):

Jitterbit and Workbench are kind of same tools. It depends upon the size of data that you are working on. If it is more than 5 million records, you should use a third party tool like Informatica etc. Both the tools are based on SOAP API but can use Bulk API, if need be. Bulk API is used if migration of huge amount of data is needed.

Also, Workbench is a tool from Salesforce but it is not supported by them. However, Data Loader is supported by Salesforce Support. So, I would suggest you to use Data Loader because if in the worst case scenario you face some issues while doing the load, then you can contact Salesforce Support.

Let me know if you have additional details. I can review them for you and let you know what I think.

Comment: Workbench author here. Do not use Workbench for any kind of large data loads. It's primarily a development and testing tool and was never designed to a handle big data loads.